# Change MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts in AspNetMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-membership

I want to change the value of `MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts` based on the user role.
For an example :

```
If user=="Admin" then MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts =1 
If user=="SupervisoR" then MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts =5
```

I am using the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider`.

How do I implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't easily set default [`MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts(v=vs.110).aspx) by assigning values to that property, since `MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts` is **getter** property. To set its value, you need to override that property and includes [`User.IsInRole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127603(v=vs.110).aspx) method from current context in a custom class derived 
 from `SqlMembershipProvider` like example below:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return 1; // example value
            }
            else if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
            {
                return 5; // example value
            }

            // define other roles here

            else
            {
                // use default if no roles provided
                return base.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in web.config, register fully qualified name of created custom class above (including its namespace) to replace default `SqlMembershipProvider`:

```
<membership ...>
   <providers>
     <add name="SqlProvider" 
          type="YourProjectNamespace.CustomMembershipProvider" ... />
   </providers>
</membership>
```